# Improving performance using array's as keys in ruby hashes

Tags: python, ruby

I need to be able to tell when two lists of objects are equal. For my application 2 lists are equal if the individual members compare equal (using ==) . For example
l1 : [a1, b1, c1] l2 : [a2, b2, c2]
l1 == l2 if (a1 == a2) and (b1 == b2) and (c1 == c2)

My current solution for this problem is to use a ruby hash with the array as key. I have overloaded the eql?(), ==() and hash() functions on my object so I get the behavior I am looking for. All of this works just fine except that performance is terrible

For example with an array size of 40 elements and a map of 1000 elements, 1000 lookups take 70ms. 
I was trying a similar implementation in python where you can use the tuple as key (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) and performance is many orders of magnitude better (about 0.4 ms)
The problem it seems is the hash computation on the array is expensive, python gets around this by having a highly optimized hash function on the tuple class that is implemented directly in c.
Thoughts on how I might improve the ruby performance?

```
class Customkey
  attr_reader :a
  attr_reader :b

  def initialize(v1, v2)
    @a = v1
    @b = v2
  end

  def hash()
    [@a, @b].hash
  end

  def ==(rhs)
    is_eql(rhs)
  end

  def eql?(rhs)
    is_eql(rhs)
  end

  def is_eql(rhs)
    return ((a == rhs.a) and (b == rhs.b))
  end
end

def random_string()
  return SecureRandom.hex(1000)
end

arr_key_map = {}
t2 = 0.0
(1..1000).each do 
  arr = []
  (1..40).each do
    a = random_string()
    b = random_string()
    arr.append(Customkey.new(a, b))
  end
  t1 = Time.now
  arr_key_map[arr] = arr[0]
  t2 += (Time.now - t1)*1000
end
puts "arr lookup " + t2.to_s
```

ruby custom_map.rb 
arr lookup 76.95500000000008

Comment: instead of roll your own timing, check out https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html for performance testing

Comment: "The problem it seems is the hash computation on the array is expensive" – Can you show us how you arrived at that conclusion? Because from looking at your code, it seems obvious that `SecureRandom` should be the bottleneck (which you call 80000 times!), especially if you have limited entropy.

Comment: The timing isn't around the SecureRandom? it is only around (arr_key_map[arr] = arr[0]) which invokes the hash function to find the correct bucket to insert into

Answer (score 0):

You should use Benchmark library to create test. However, if you want to use your own metrics, I do a small refactor and now numbers are very similar.

```
class Customkey
  attr_reader :a
  attr_reader :b

  def initialize(v1, v2)
    @a = v1
    @b = v2
  end

  def ==(rhs)
    a == rhs.a && b == rhs.b
  end
end
```

```
class PerformanceTest
  def self.execute
    arr_key_map = {}
    t1 = Time.now
    (1..1000).each do
      arr = []
      (1..40).each do
        a = SecureRandom.hex(1000)
        b = SecureRandom.hex(1000)
        arr << Customkey.new(a, b)
      end
      arr_key_map[arr] = arr[0]
    end
    t2 = Time.now - t1
    puts "arr lookup #{t2}"
  end
end
```

Results:

```
arr lookup 0.416363
arr lookup 0.479958
arr lookup 0.412217
...
```

Comment: this maybe of some help but does not answer the question

Comment: I'm trying to say that metrics that were reported are incorrect. Performance in Ruby or Python, in this particular case is very similar. Just refactor the code and you will see.

Comment: can yo provide the refactor you're referring to? The OP has methods in `CustomKey` class which are never called.

Answer (score 0):

Not even sure exactly what you're trying to test here because none of your class instance methods are even getting called here, but you're just running a loop. SecureRandom being called over and over in a loop is going to be slow.  Use [Benchmark library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) to test performance.

```
require 'SecureRandom'
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report(:a) {  1000.times {SecureRandom.hex(1000) } }
  x.report(:b) {  1000.times {SecureRandom.hex(10) } }
end

       user     system      total        real
a  0.009310   0.037258   0.046568 (  0.047257)
b  0.003325   0.011982   0.015307 (  0.015520)
```

Here's a modified version of your code to see what you think you're trying to test with unused methods removed:

```
require 'SecureRandom'
require 'benchmark'
class Customkey
  attr_reader :a
  attr_reader :b

  def initialize(v1, v2)
    @a = v1
    @b = v2
  end

  def hash()
    [@a, @b].hash
  end
end

def random_string()
  SecureRandom.hex(1000)
end

arr_key_map = {}
arr = []
1000.times do
  (1..40).each do
    a = random_string()
    b = random_string()
    arr.append(Customkey.new(a, b))
  end
end

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('one') { arr_key_map[arr] = arr[0] }
  x.report('40k') do
    array = []
    1000.times do
      (1..40).each do
        a = random_string()
        b = random_string()
        array.append(Customkey.new(a, b))
      end
    end
  end
end

       user     system      total        real
one  0.079796   0.001234   0.081030 (  0.081704)
40k  0.594674   2.779321   3.373995 (  3.461908)
```

Comment: On my system your script give this result for 40k : 
40k  0.312000   0.031000   0.343000 (  0.344641)


The result is the same for one.

Comment: "none of your class instance methods are even getting called here" – That is not correct. `Customkey#initialize` is called by `Class#new`, `Customkey#hash` is *definitely* called by `Hash#[]=`, `Customkey#eql?` will be called by `Hash#[]=` in case of a hash collision, in which case also `Customkey#is_eql?` will be called by `Customkey#eql?`. So, `Customkey#initialize` and `Customkey#hash` will *always* be called, and `Customkey#eql?` and `Customkey#is_eql?` will *sometimes* be called. The only method that will *definitely not* be called is `Customkey#==`, however, it is good practice to …

Comment: … always override `#eql?`, `#hash`, and `#==` together.

Comment: @JörgWMittag i tested adding a 'puts method_name' inside each method and only `initialize` and `hash` get called in the context of the given code, but ok.